# How to prevent people from accessing source videos without logining in?

Tags: php, apache, authentication

I am trying to make a login that would give you access to some videos, pictures, and other files. I can do this with php and a get request (`www.example.com/foo?video1`) and making sure they have a cookie of some sort, but I am unsure how to prevent someone from just typing in the link of the source files (`www.example.com/videos/video1.mp4`). I need away to prevent people from accessing the source files.

System:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.6
- Apache

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Why can't you check for logged in user before granting access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the source files in some directory that is not public, or use an HTAccess.
Then, use file_get_contents() and echo to spit out the video.
It might look something like this:

getvideo.php?video=test

```
    <?php
if($_SESSION["username"]!==null)//whatever auth mechanism
{
if(file_exists("videos/".  str_replace( [ '\\', '.', '/'], '', $_GET["video"] ). ".mp4"))
{
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
readfile("videos/".  str_replace( [ '\\', '.', '/'], '', $_GET["video"] ). ".mp4");
}

else
{
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
}
}
else
{
header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
}
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea if you're using Apache.

Make sure the [Rewrite module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) is turned on.

Create a .htaccess file in your videos directory with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule . video.php?video=$1
```

Now, create a file named video.php with something like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * require your login / db files here
 * and check if the user is logged in,
 * if it isn't redirect back or whatever you need
 */

$video = $_GET['video'];
$video = str_replace('..', '', $video); // prevent ../../file 

if (file_exists($video)) {
    header('Content-type: ' . mime_content_type($video));
    echo file_get_contents($video);
} else {
    // 404...
}
```

Now you can call yoursite.com/videos/video.mp4 and place your video files in the videos directory.